# Find all the solutions of the following linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have tried to solve the following congruence

$2x \cong 5 (mod\ 7)$

Using the following diophantian equation: $
    2x - 7y = 5 \\ $

Solution: 
    $
7 = 2(3) + 1\\
2 = 1(2)  $

This gives

$ 1= 7 - 2(3)$

Multiplying both sides with 5 gives

$ 5= (5) 7 - 2(15) \implies x_0=-15\ \& \space y_0 = -5$

When checking if the equation is satisfied I can see that it is since 
$-30 - (-5)(7) = 5 $

I however don't believe that I have done everything correctly, since I can see that x =6 and y = 1 is also a solution and that is the solution that I am supposed to get. Also d = gcd(2,7) = 1 which should imply that there should only be one incongruent solution modolo m.

What might my mistake be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need to recall the following known result:

> **Theorem.** Let $\gcd(a,n)=d$. If $x_0$ is a solution of $ax\equiv b\pmod n$ then the $d$ incongruent solutions are given by
>   $$x_0,x_0+\frac{n}{d},x_0+\frac{2n}{d},\dots,x_0+\frac{(d-1)n}{d}.$$

Going back to your question: We have 
$$2x\equiv 5\pmod 7.$$
One can see that $x_0=-1$ is a particular solution. Since $\gcd(2,7)=1$, the given congruence has exactly one solution (given as a set). It is given by all $x$ such that 
$$x\equiv -1\pmod 7.$$ Since $-1\equiv 6\pmod 7$, the general solution is any $x$ for which 
$$x\equiv 6\pmod 7.$$

---

From your solution, $x_0=-15$, meaning that the solution is $$x\equiv -15\pmod 7$$ but $-15\equiv 6\pmod 7$ implying that the general solution is 
$$x\equiv 6\pmod 7.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;\;2x \equiv 5 \pmod 7 \;\iff\;2x \equiv -2 \pmod 7 \;\iff\; x \equiv -1 \pmod 7$

Answer (score 0):

All solutions for $2x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ are as following:

$$2x = 7\cdot k + 5 \Rightarrow x= \frac{7\cdot k + 5}{2}; \forall k \in \mathbb{Z^+} \mid k \equiv 1 \pmod 2$$

Another point not involving odd multiples is $x= 6 + 7\cdot k, \forall k \in \mathbb{N_0}$

Comment: I have read the other comments, and I grasp them I also understand your answer, but could you elaborate further why $x_0=−15 & y_0=−5$ is incorrect, or is it? Also since d = 1 does not that imply that there should only be one class of solutions?

Comment: $x_0=-15,y_0=-5$ seems fine for me, I have only take into account the positive solutions, but can be negative as well. If $d \neq 1$, then it will be congruent $0 \mod 7$.